# .p12 certificate not working on mac (Ventura 13.4.1) but works on windows

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, mac, self-signed-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

I generated ssl certificates for (Nifi Registry https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) I installed them in Windows.. it worked and i get a prompt to select certificate when i open the website https://

Now, when i install them in Mac, first it wont work out of box. Mac says unsupported format. After some googling, someone suggested to change the format from p12 to cer. I followed this (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446790/mac-import-p12-certificate-into-the-keychain-via-command-line) answer and converted to .cer format. with .cer format it got added to keychain (I can see it in keychains of mac)
but still when i access my webpage, it says localhost didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided. ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT .
Generally it should prompt me to select certificate and display UI. but its not working as expected.

So i think, Mac is somehow not able to process the certificate.

Is there a way that i can add this .p12 certificate correctly to mac and make my website work ?

Please help or suggest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's also posted on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565552/p12-certificate-not-working-on-mac-ventura-13-4-1